# Преобразование даты в Unix (в SQL запросе)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть множество решений как преобразовать дату формата unix в нормальный вид при запросе в базу. Но вот ответа как сделать обратно я не нашел.

То есть дата в базе хранится в виде `d-m-Y H:i:s`, разумеется сравнивать такую дату с такой же не вариант. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > 1501599222` - не сработает правильно.

Как преобразовать обычную дату в unix?

Comment: вам для какой СУБД надо?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для преобразования даты в timestamp в Mysql можно использовать следующую конструкцию

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2017-12-01 13:16:18', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

Для обратного преобразования

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2017-12-01 13:16:18', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Если Вам необходимо для другой БД, тогда укажите для какой именно, так как синтакис может отличатся

Comment: Не совсем понял, как мне поставить его в сравнение? Так? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2017-12-01 13:16:18', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) > 1501599222` ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) > 1501599222 только формат нужно указать соттветсвующий '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'

Comment: А по какой причине в решили передавать дату в запрос в timestamp, а не в более привычном '2017-12-01 13:16:18'? MySQL нормально сравнивает даты и в таком формате

Comment: Спасибо большое Антон, без Вас бы переделывал все. Я сравнивал такие форматы, он совершенно не тот результат выдает.